# Regex to find last letter in word for any String

Tags: java, regex

I have a small problem with Regular Expressions ( regex ).

I want to remove any "T" at the end of each word in the string.
This is the code I am using to display all the words ending with "T".

```
public static void main (String []args){
    String name = "PHYLAURHEIMSMET hello tttttyyuolktttb fedqs jhgjt";
    p = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]+)?[t]");
    m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: It'll be good to include your expected output.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking or what is your _blocking_ problem. You want to produce a string where all T, at the end of words, are removed?

Comment: the problem is resolved :
string.replaceAll("T(?!\\S)", "");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i try to remove any "T" at the end of each word

```
string.replaceAll("T(?!\\S)", "");
```

This would match all the `T`'s which was present at the end of each word.

**OR**

```
string.replaceAll("T(?=\\s|$)", "");
```

This would match all the `t`'s only if it's follwed by a space or end of the line anchor.

To do  a case-insensitive replacement.

```
string.replaceAll("(?i)T(?!\\S)", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pL2lR2/1)

Comment: thank you for your back on it, my problem is finally solved thanks to your solution

Comment: is it possible to match a word commance with a letter ( "x") and finished with a letter ( "y" ) by any character in the string

Comment: you may try this `(?<!\\S)x\\S*y(?!\\S)`

Comment: the question is:
replaced ("s") by ("z") if followed and preceded by the letters a, e, i , o, u

Comment: `replaceAll("(?<=[aeiou])s(?=[aeiou])", "z");`

Comment: it works really , how you doing to find the solution :)
thank you a lot

Comment: one last question then finally:
replace the following groups of 2 letters ("an") and ("in"), unless it is followed by a, e, i, o, u
think's

Comment: @yougho ask this as a new question.

Comment: where? i don't inderstand your question

Comment: @yougho if you have any further queries, pls ask it as a new question.

Comment: @yougho You should be able to answer that question by yourself based on already posted comments (unless you simply copy-paste solutions without trying to understand them, in which case you probably should ask answerer for clarifications).

Comment: @AvinashRaj If you take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622440/regex-string-using-java) you will see that OP asked very bad question. I suspect that this happened because he doesn't understand solution posted here and don't know about look-around mechanisms. Could you edit your answer and add explanation what is `(?=...)` or `(?!...)` preferably with links to articles like http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html which explains it in more detail?

Comment: yes it's true it's not good for me but until now I realized everything alone and that 3 days I 'm working on it, the only remaining étè care about me this voila,
I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `\b` word-boundary to test if the letter is at the end of the word, you can see the result of replacing `t\b` with an empty string on [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pP1wQ0/2).

I'm not sure if you want to **only** remove upper case T's, in that case, remove the `i` all the way to the right.

In Java that would be:

```
string.replaceAll("T\b", ""); // <-- only upper case T's
string.replaceAll("(?i)T\b", ""); // <-- both t and T's
```

Comment: @vks is that the end of a word? I would say not but depends on the context.

Comment: sry i meant `abctT!@`

Comment: the problem is resolved : 
string.replaceAll("T(?!\\S)", "");

Answer (score 0):

This is just suggetion why not to use simple String class inbuilt functions something like this :

```
String name = "PHYLAURHEIMSMET hello tttttyyuolktttb fedqs jhgjt";
        if ('t' == name.charAt(name.length() - 1) || 'T' == name.charAt(name.length() - 1)) {
            System.out.println("contains last char 't' or 'T'");
        }
```